Dataprovider+TestNG - Exception in thread "surefire-forkedjvm-command-thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
I have a test automation framework based on testng and dataprovider . I run my code on server with the help of jenkins job . This job executes testcases using maven command line . This job was taking a time of over 3 hrs to execute so I wanted to run my test cases in parallel/concurrently for which I added parallel=true to my dataprovider method.
@DataProvider(name = "data-provider",**parallel = true**)
    protected Object[][] Credentials { return objArray[][];}

But when this jenkins job is run on Azure then I am getting below exception .

Exception in thread "surefire-forkedjvm-command-thread"
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space   at
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.iterator(ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java:669)
at
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.CommandReader$CommandRunnable.insertToListeners(CommandReader.java:469)
at
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.CommandReader$CommandRunnable.run(CommandReader.java:424)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Please let me know what are my options as it seems my heap size gets exhausted . I also tried to specify below in my pom.xml but did not work .
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m</argLine>

No thread-count Or parallel details specified in TestNG.xml & neither in dataprovider method .
Just used this @DataProvider(name = "data-provider",parallel = true)
However earlier I tried using below in testng.xml . But may be I was'nt able to configure the threads correctly bcos while running the suite it used to get stuck .
<suite name="API AMS regression suite" verbose="10"  data-provider-thread-count="20" >
  
    <test name="POS Testcases">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.qa.apis.tests.Pos"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suites>


Can you give more details which Maven version, JDK version, plugin versions do you use? How does the full configuration look like etc.

You mentioned that you enabled data provider parallelism. Can you also show us what does your suite file look like ? Please edit your question and add the suite file contents along with the TestNG version that you are using. The root cause is mostly because you turned on data provider parallelism with a larger threadpool size and coupled it with a parallelism turned on at method level.

So lets say you have your thread-count as 20 and your data provider thread count as 10, and parallel as methods, then you are literally telling TestNG to spawn 20 * 19 threads (I am assuming that all your tests are data driven tests). This is just a guess.

hi @KrishnanMahadevan , yes all my tests are data provider tests . My each TC will run 20 rows fetched from excel (so yes 20 threads should run parallely per TC) . I have not specified threadcount anywhere and no changes in testng.xml . Earlier I did try this in my testNg file - 

The root cause for the OutOfMemoryError is most likely due to your tests creating a lot of threads.
TestNG has 2 thread pools at it's disposal

thread-count - Represents how many regular test methods (which are NOT driven by a data provider) can run in parallel. It has a default value of 5.
data-provider-thread-count - Represents how many data driven tests can run in parallel at any given point in time. It also requires that you set @DataProvider(parallel=true). It has a default value of 10.

Let's assume that you set parallel=methods at the <suite> level or at the <test> level :

Let's say you have 5 test methods in your project then TestNG will run all the 5 methods in parallel.
Now, if all your 5 test methods are actually data provider powered methods and configured to run in parallel via @DataProvider(parallel=true) then TestNG is essentially going to run 5*10 = 50 threads in parallel.

Depending on your machine configuration and your memory configuration, the OS may or may not be able to create that many number of threads.
You have a few options to bring this to your control.

Reduce the number of threads for data-provider-thread-count and also explicitly specify a value for thread-count
Move to using TestNG 7.10.2 which now contains a couple of new features that will help you manage this by allowing you to use a shared thread pool.

For the sake of completeness, I am quoting the relevant sections from the documentation

share-thread-pool-for-data-providers - When this attribute is set to
true at the suite level, TestNG will start using a shared thread pool
for all the data driven tests in a given . The size of the
thread pool is determined using the attribute
data-provider-thread-count. This attribute has a default value of
false.
use-global-thread-pool - When this attribute is set to true at the
suite level, TestNG will start using a common thread pool for running
both your regular test methods and data driven test methods. The size
of the thread pool is determined using the attribute thread-count.
This attribute has a default value of false.

For a detailed explanation please see https://testng.org/#_controlling_threadpool_usage
PS: When you use use-global-thread-pool and when you have some data driven tests, there's a chance that you may stumble into this bug https://github.com/testng-team/testng/issues/3028
Please go through this defect to understand what causes this problem.
This issue has been fixed in the latest snapshot version of TestNG and should be available for use with 7.11.0. Basically this new version will attempt at detecting possible deadlocks and warn you accordingly by halting your execution.
